# How to create a android.graphicsPicture object in android

Tags: android, canvas, image

I want to use Canvas class's drawPicture(Picture picture, Rect dst) method.
Now I don't know how to create this Picture object. I want to pass in a 9 patch image file as the Picture object which will be kept in res/drawable folder of my project.
How do I create this picture object ?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create Picture object, then you need an input stream:
[Picture class android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html)

Why you would choose this method is beyond me though. But thats your choice :-)

Comment: Actually What I need is that to draw a rectangle and a have a picture/image which always fills this rectangle.

Comment: Isn't Imageview, with setImageResource(int resId) what you need instead then?